# Camera access in docker container is generating errors / locking

Tags: python, picamera, docker

I am trying to build some machine vision software inside docker containers, it has worked previously, but now both devices are not able to access the camera.

It seems to be a configuration/update problem, as it has worked previously. I am not sure which of the updates could be the culprit.

Either calling "raspistill -i test.jpg" never returns (freeze) or this error appears:

```
mmal: mmal_vc_shm_init: could not initialize vc shared memory service
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to initialise shm for 'vc.camera_info' (7:EIO)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.camera_info' (7)
mmal: Failed to create camera_info component
```

As it has previously worked in the container, access to the device, and hardware-challenges are ruled out.

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error message, you probably don't have the correct permissions. Try adding `privileged: true` to your docker-compose.yml file (or something like --privileged=true if you are using `docker run`).

(I assume there was a typo when you posted your command. To test, it should be `raspistill -o test.jpg`.)

Comment: Thanks, typo indeed. But adding the privileged thing did not change anything.

Comment: what was your typo? I'm getting this error too

Answer (score 0):

I found it's a problem with the udev rules.
There's a file

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/99-com.rules
```

that seems to come with the os.

This file contains udev rules for the camera device so that even if you create a 99-camera.rules file it does not seem to apply.
So what I did to solve the problem was just to add/modify these lines:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="vchiq", GROUP="video", MODE="0666"
KERNEL=="vcsm-cma", GROUP="video", MODE="0666"
SUBSYSTEM=="dma_heap", GROUP="video", MODE="0666"
```

Notice the MODE='066**6**', so you do not need to remove the group as some guides say.